# Unable to run evil-winrm (some problem with ffi)

Tags: windows, kali-linux, remote-desktop

I am getting this error when running evil-winrm:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from /usr/local/bin/evil-winrm:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `activate_bin_path'
    14: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `synchronize'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:305:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1440:in `activate'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1458:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1458:in `each'
     9: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1472:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1440:in `activate'
     7: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1458:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1458:in `each'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1472:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1440:in `activate'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1458:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1458:in `each'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1469:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:310:in `to_specs': Could not find 'ffi' (>= 1.0.1) among 123 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/jayhawk/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/var/lib/gems/2.5.0:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.5.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

Comment: This is not a security question. This is a runtime error you need to troubleshoot.

Comment: gem uninstall evil-winrm
gem cleanup evil-winrm
gem install evil-winrm #these commands worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your local Gemfile contains the following:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'winrm'
gem 'winrm-fs'
gem 'stringio'
```

Which you can install with `bundle install` whilst on the same directory as the file above. You'll need `bundler` (under debian based distros that's the `ruby-bundler` package)

To install `ffi` on its own you can do:
`gem install ffi`